# Задача с функцией Javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

Описание задания

Пользуясь переменной user из задания 2, напишите функцию printChatUsers, которая выведет список собеседников в переписке.
Имена не должны повторяться

Пример:

```js
let user = {
    name: "Мистер дудец",
    login: "mrdudec",
    reputation: 15,
    messages: [
      {from: "oleg", text: "Вам нужно больше кальция!"},
      {from: "Илья", text: "Просто растворите мел в воде"},
      {from: "Иван", text: "Да, это уникальное советское средство :)"},
      {from: "Илья", text: "Иван, тебе 12 лет, ты не знаешь, что было в советах"},
      {from: "oleg", text: "Друзья, пожалуйста, держите себя в руках"},
      {from: "Илья", text: "Мой друг - администратор"}, 
      {from: "administrator", text: "Чат удалён"},
    ]
};

1
printChatUsers();
```

выведет:

```
12
В чате пользователей: 4
Вот они: oleg, Илья, Иван, administrator
```

Обратите внимание на то, что в примере сообщений 6, но авторов - 4.
Процесс реализации

Объявите переменную user и заполните её тестовыми данными из задания 2
Убедитесь, что переменная user не объявлена внутри функции. В теле функции выполните действия:

Напечатайте заголовок: В чате пользователей: X, где X - количество пользователей
из функции обратитесь к переменной user. Напечатайте имена отправителей без повторения через запятую

Шаблон:

```
1
Вот они: имя1, имя2, имя3, имя4
```

Решение

```js
let user = {
    name: "Иван Иванов",
    login: "killer504",
    reputation: 97,
    messages: [
      {from: "administrator", text: "Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме"},
      {from: "Петр", text: "Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?"},
      {from: "administrator", text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем DonkeyKong"},
      {from: "administrator", text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем Netologist"},
      {from: "Brian Kerninghan", text: "hello, world"}
    ]
};

function userCall() {
      let a = user.messages.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) { / Вот тут нужно что то дописать или строчкой ниже /
            if (a  

            }
    
    
        let b = user.messages[0].from;
          let c = user.messages[1].from;
      
             let d = user.messages[4].from;

       
    console.log('В чате пользователей: ' + a);
     console.log('Вот они : ' +  b + ', ' + c + ', ' + d );
    }
  
userCall ();
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Нужно чтобы в консоль вывел количество уникальных пользователей в  чате , но сейчас он выдает 5 , нужно как то отфидьтровать их и сделать чтобы выводил только уникальных

Comment: Пробегитесь по массиву, в новый массив откладывайте уникальных пользователей. Проверить на наличие элемента в массиве можн с помощью метода [includes](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof-i-includes)

Comment: А циклом это сделать можно без создания нового массива?

Comment: Все равно нужно же где-то хранить тех, кто уже был "учтен"...

Comment: ```let set = new Set(user.messages.map(msg => msg.from)); console.log(`В чате пользователей: ${set.size}`); console.log(`Вот они: ${[...set].join(', ')}`);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Напечатайте имена отправителей без повторения через запятую

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
let user = {
  name: "Иван Иванов",
  login: "killer504",
  reputation: 97,
  messages: [{
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Вы получили предупреждение за публикацию рекламы на форуме"
    },
    {
      from: "Петр",
      text: "Собираем встречу в субботу в 19:00. Придёшь?"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем DonkeyKong"
    },
    {
      from: "administrator",
      text: "Ваш рейтинг был повышен пользователем Netologist"
    },
    {
      from: "Brian Kerninghan",
      text: "hello, world"
    }
  ]
};

function userCall() {
  const s = user.messages.reduce((s, o) => (s.add(o.from), s), new Set())

  console.log('В чате пользователей: ' + s.size);
  console.log('Вот они : ' + [...s].join(', '));
}

userCall();
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение